# Advantages of cv::Matx

Tags: opencv, matrix

I noticed that a new data structure **cv::Matx** was added to the new **OpenCV** version, intended for small matrices of known size at compilation time, for example

```
cv::Matx31f  // matrix 3x1 of float type
```

Checking the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=matx#Matx) I saw that most of matrix operations are available, but still I don't see the advantages of using this new type instead of the old cv::Mat.

When should I use Matx instead of Mat?

Comment: Without looking too closely into the documentation, one can say that knowing the size at compile time has surely many advantages, first of all the replacement of dynamically allocated memory by compile time arrays, which for such small clearly defined matrices is an obvious optimization. That being said, your question answers it quite clearly: *"intended for small matrices of known size"*. Think of transformation matrices as used in image transformations or camera calibration.

Comment: But that still can be done with the old type Mat by putting Mat(3,1,CV_32FC1)

Comment: Sure, therefore my whole first paragraph about the obvious optimization of using compile time arrays over dynamic memory allocation. Of course it is just an optimization and no additional functionality, but exactly this is the advantage you get. You don't really want to dynamically allocate memory for a strict 3x4 matrix.

Comment: I use them whenever I can and I think they improve readability.  Matx33f is a very intuitive type name and when several different types of transformations are involved it helps differentiate them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's about memory management and not wasting (in some cases important) memory or just reservation of memory for an object you'll use later.

That's how I understand it – may be someone else can give a better explanation.

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: cv::Mat uses the heap to store its data, while cv::Matx uses the stack.

A cv::Mat uses dynamic memory allocation (on the heap). This is appropriate for big matrices (like images) and lets you do things like shallow copies of a matrix, which is the default behavior of cv::Mat.

However, for the small matrices that cv::Matx is designed for, heap allocation would be very expensive compared to doing the same thing on the stack. I have seen a block of math reduce processing time by over 75% by switching to using stack-allocated types (e.g. cv::Point and cv::Matx) instead of cv::Mat.

Comment: I believe much performance is also gained by loop unrolling, which can't be done for dynamic-sized matrices.

Answer (score 8):

This is a late late answer, but it is still an interesting question!

dom's answer is quite accurate, and the heap/stack reference in user1460044's is also interesting.

From a practical point of view, **I wouldn't use** `Matx` (or `Vec`), except if it were completely necessary. The major advantages of Matx are

1. Using the stack (*efficient*![1])
2. Initialization.

The problem is, at the end you will have to move your `Matx` data to a `Mat` to do most of stuff, and so, you will be back at the heap again.
On the other hand, the "cool initialization" of a `Matx` can be done in a normal Mat:

```
// Matx initialization:
Matx31f A(1.f,2.f,3.f);
// Mat initialization:
Mat B = (Mat_<float>(3,1) << 1.f, 2.f, 3.f);
```

Also, there is a difference in initialization (beyond the heap/stack) stuff. If you try to put 5 values into the Matx31, it will crash (runtime exception), while calling the `Mat_::operator<<` with 5 values will only store the first three.

[1] *Efficient* if your program has to create lots of matrices of less than ~10 elements. In that case use `Matx` matrices.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 other reasons why I prefer `Matx` to `Mat`:

1. Readability: people reading the code can immediately see the size of the matrices, for example:

   ```
   cv::Matx34d transform = ...;
   ```

   It's clear that this is a 3x4 matrix, so it contains a 3D transformation of type (R,t), where R is a rotation matrix (as opposed to say, axis-angle).
   Similarly, accessing an element is more natural with `transform(i,j)` vs `transform.at<double>(i,j)`.
2. Easy debugging. Since the elements for `Matx` are allocated on the stack in an array of known length, IDEs or debuggers can display the entire contents nicely when stepping through the code.